# Find the missing record and replicate it on a monthly basis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I had a time series dataframe like below, but the records are not completed for each month. I would like to replicate every records with it's latest status and number till the last month.

```
   Month      Client  Status     Revenue
0   2019-03-01     A      A           100
1   2019-04-01     A      T           null
2   2019-03-01     B      A           200
3   2019-05-01     B      A           200
4   2019-06-01     B      T           null
5   2019-03-01     C      A           150
6   2019-04-01     C      A           200
7   2019-05-01     C      T           null
8   2019-06-01     C      T           null
```

The expected output would like below, thanks!

```
     Month      Client  Status     Revenue 
0   2019-03-01     A      A           100 
1   2019-04-01     A      T           100 
2   2019-05-01     A      T           100 
3   2019-06-01     A      T           100 
4   2019-03-01     B      A           200 
5   2019-04-01     B      A           200 
6   2019-05-01     B      A           200 
7   2019-06-01     B      T           200 
8   2019-03-01     C      A           150 
9   2019-04-01     C      A           200 
10  2019-05-01     C      T           200 
11  2019-06-01     C      T           200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
# convert the column Revenue to Int64, to avoid converting 
# the values to floats during the merge process
# if you don't mind them being floats, you can just skip
# ths step
df['Revenue']= df['Revenue'].astype('Int64')

# create a new index for a dataframe to get the missing rows
# the index is a mulitindex containing the values of the 
# cartesian product of the unique values in the Client column
# and the dates in range 2019-03-01 - 2019-06-01
new_index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Client'].unique(), pd.date_range(start='2019-03-01', end='2019-06-01', freq='MS')])

# now use this to create a dataframe that contains a row for each
# output row, we want to see and uses the index we just created
merged= pd.DataFrame({'Month': new_index.get_level_values(1)}, index=new_index).merge(df, right_on=['Client', 'Month'], left_index=True, how='left', suffixes=['', '_old'])

# remove the old Month column to get the same column layout as before
# and fill the missing values with the last known value for the client
#
# I almost missed the problem with "forwarding" values to the next
# client. Thank you @ifly6 for bringing up this point.
merged.drop(['Month_old'], axis='columns', inplace=True)
merged[['Status', 'Revenue']]= merged[['Client', 'Status', 'Revenue']].groupby(['Client'], sort=False, as_index=False).ffill()
```

The result is:

```
       Month Client Status  Revenue
0 2019-03-01      A      A      100
1 2019-04-01      A      T      100
8 2019-05-01      A      T      100
8 2019-06-01      A      T      100
2 2019-03-01      B      A      200
8 2019-04-01      B      A      200
3 2019-05-01      B      A      200
4 2019-06-01      B      T      200
5 2019-03-01      C      A      150
6 2019-04-01      C      A      200
7 2019-05-01      C      T      200
8 2019-06-01      C      T      200
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('Client').ffill()
Out[75]: 
  Client       Month Status  Revenue
0      A  2019-03-01      A    100.0
1      A  2019-04-01      T    100.0
2      B  2019-03-01      A    200.0
3      B  2019-05-01      A    200.0
4      B  2019-06-01      T    200.0
5      C  2019-03-01      A    150.0
6      C  2019-04-01      A    200.0
7      C  2019-05-01      T    200.0
8      C  2019-06-01      T    200.0
```

You could do a forward fill not by group, but that could mix data between clients.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the missing record for client A in May and Jun are not replicated.

Comment: Then you need to resample